# "the following query has failed" error executing a stored routine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created the following stored procedure in phpMyAdmin Version: 4.1.14.3 running on a ZYXEL NS325 NAS. It appears in the routines list for the database.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `getDuplicateApplicationCyclePersons`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    PROCEDURE `getDuplicateApplicationCyclePersons`() 
        NOT DETERMINISTIC 
        CONTAINS SQL 
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    SELECT * FROM ApplicationCycle
```

However, when I execute the routine from the routines list, I get "the following query failed" but with no error details i.e. "MySql said:"

The query runs in the SQL window. I have tried several simple procedures on this new database all with the same result. Any ideas why they wont run?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. I suggest you call the routine from a sql window and see if that gives you  more of a clue.

Comment: Try without DEFINER

Comment: Tried every which way. This message appears when I navigate to the routines tab..."You are using PHP's deprecated 'mysql' extension, which is not capable of handling multi queries. The execution of some stored routines may fail! Please use the improved 'mysqli' extension to avoid any problems."